# How to get the value of <p:editor> after update

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, rich-text-editor

As a feature in my JSF Web application, i need online editing for word documents.
In order to update a word document that i have in my database table i do the following :

1/create the datatable and the column which contains the Commandlinks that shows the dialogue that has the `<p:editor>`.(used datatable binding in a sessionscoped Managedbean)

```
//the creation of the column that has Commandlinks.
CommandLink rapstatelink = (CommandLink) application.createComponent(CommandLink.COMPONENT_TYPE);
rapstatelink.setId("MRepShowButton");
rapstatelink.setUpdate(":form1:formero");
rapstatelink.setOnclick("EditorDialog.show();");

ValueExpression value = ef.createValueExpression(elc, "#{exam}", Cotation.class);
ValueExpression target = ef.createValueExpression(elc, "#{dyna.selectedExamen}", Cotation.class);

//this two lines should update the editor with the loaded doc from datatabase.
rapstatelink.addActionListener(new SetPropertyActionListenerImpl(target, value));
ValueExpression value1 = ef.createValueExpression(elc, "#{dyna.selectedExamen.examen.rapport.rapportWrittenFile}", byte[].class);
ValueExpression target1 = ef.createValueExpression(elc, "#{dyna.raptext}", byte[].class);
rapstatelink.addActionListener(new SetPropertyActionListenerImpl(target1, value1)); 
column.getChildren().add(rapstatelink);
table.getChildren().add(column);
```

2/create the dialogue that contains the  on my jsf page :

```
<!-this is wrapped in a global form id="form1"->
<p:dialog header="Compte rendu"
          widgetVar="EditorDialog"
          resizable="true"
          id="patDlg"
          showEffect="fade"
          hideEffect="drop"
          modal="true"
          position ="center middle"
          maximizable="true"
          dynamic="true"
          width="1200"
          height="850">  
          <h:panelGrid id="display" ellpadding="4" style="margin:0 auto;">  
            <h:form id="formero">
              <p:messages id="msg2" showDetail="true" closable="true" />
              <p:editor id="editoreo"
                        value="#{dyna.raptext}"
                        converter="#{HTMLConverter}"
                        width="1100"
                        height="700" /> 
              <h:panelGrid columns="3" style="margin-top:10px">  
                <p:commandButton id="submitButton"
                                 value="Enregistrer"
                                 actionListener="#{dyna.saveDoc(dyna.selectedExamen.examen.rapport.rapportId)}" 
                                 process="@this" update="msg2"
                                 icon="ui-icon-disk" />
                <p:commandButton id="clearButton"
                                 type="button"
                                 value="Vider"
                                 onclick="editoreo.clear();"  
                                 icon="ui-icon-refresh" />
                <p:commandButton id="hideButton"
                                 type="button" 
                                 value="Annuler"
                                 onclick="EditorDialog.hide();"  
                                 icon="ui-icon-close" />  
              </h:panelGrid>   
            </h:form>   
           </h:panelGrid> 
</p:dialog>
```

3/this is the saveDoc() method that updates the table :

```
public void saveDoc(String idr) {

    try {
        //raptext is a field in the same managed bean.(session scoped)
        DAO_Examen.UpdateRapporttext(raptext, idr);
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Terminé avec succes", "operation bien effectué " + idr + "|||||");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

    } catch (Exception c) {

        c.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

--Just in case here is my HTMLConverter :

```
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    try {
        if (value != null) {
            ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) value);
            HWPFDocumentCore wordDocument = WordToHtmlUtils.loadDoc(bin);
            WordToHtmlConverter wordToHtmlConverter = new WordToHtmlConverter(DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                    .newDocumentBuilder().newDocument());
            wordToHtmlConverter.processDocument(wordDocument);
            Document htmlDocument = wordToHtmlConverter.getDocument();
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(htmlDocument);
            StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(out);
            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer serializer = tf.newTransformer();
            serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
            serializer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
            out.close();
            value = new String(out.toByteArray());
            return (String) value;

        } else {
            return "";
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }

}
```

### **The Question :**

Evreything works fine, but when i fire the action from the command button i don't get the edited text, i get the same very text that i loaded in the first time with no modification.
I want to know how may i get the value of the new edited text, so i can save it to the datatabse.

Comment: How do you know that you are not "getting" the edited text? Are you checking it in the UpdateRapporttext() method (or anywhere else in the Java code), or are you seeing if something changes in the database?

Comment: i have a System.out.println(); in the saveDoc() method.

Comment: No answer, please regrad this question ?

Comment: what possibly could be wrong in my implementation please help me, i'm most eager to know.

Comment: I have no idea what can be wrong here, otherwise I would have certainly posted it :/ I've used p:editor myself no problem, only I didn't use a converter. In PrimeFaces 3, I have not had the pleasure of trying out PrimeFaces 4 yet.

Comment: even without the converter it won't work, the problem is it sticks to the first value it had , it's like it won't get the new text.